# jQuery not working after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a data center selection script that will, when clicked, change the selected flag and also show/hide two divs with plans and stuff.

However, when I add `$("#conteudoID").hide()` to my jQuery code, it breaks everything (without this, it changes the color/selected flag correctly).

This the the fiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/rbaldasso/g5ax9nbn/2/

Code:

```js
$("#conteudo2").hide();
$("#conteudo1").hide();

$('.childDiv').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('background-color', '#4f5154')
  $("#conteudo2").hide()
  $("#conteudo1").show()
    .siblings(".childDiv")
    .css('background-color', '#9c9c9c')
  $("#conteudo2").show()
  $("#conteudo1").hide();
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Escolha um Data Center</h3>
<div class="container" id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv fixed" id="child1">
    <img src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/br.svg" width="90px">
    <br>Brasil - São Paulo</div>
  <div class="childDiv flex-item" id="child2">
    <img src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/us.svg" width="90px">
    <br>Estados Unidos - Kansas</div>
</div>

<div id="conteudo1" class="conteudo">
  apareci br
</div>
<div id="conteudo2" class="conteudo">
  apareci eua
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you hiding and showing divs with no delay? that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $("#conteudo2").hide();
        $("#conteudo1").hide();

        $('#child1').click(function(){
            $(this)
            .css('background-color','#4f5154')
            .siblings(".childDiv")
            .css('background-color','#9c9c9c');

            $("#conteudo1").show();
            $("#conteudo2").hide();
        });

        $('#child2').click(function(){
            $(this)
            .css('background-color','#4f5154')
            .siblings(".childDiv")
            .css('background-color','#9c9c9c');

            $("#conteudo2").show();
            $("#conteudo1").hide();
        });
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But you shouldn't just post code. You should explain what's wrong with the original code, and how your answer fixes it.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Here it is: You are showing and hiding your "conteudo" divs at the same time in your function.

Comment: Not in comments, put it in the answer itself.

Comment: And while you're editing, fix your indentation. You could also create a stack snippet so we can see it in action.

Comment: Ok, but I think it's unnecessary to add the snippet, as the OP had the code in _fiddle_...

Comment: I copied his fiddle to a snippet. So you can easily copy that to your answer and make the changes, then we can see it working.

Comment: @Rodrigo B., is there any reason why you have unaccepted the answer?